# Need help understanding probability problem

Tags: math, statistics, probability

I'm studying for my statistics exam next week, and I'm struggling with probabilities, in particular when it comes to determining which formulas to use in order to tackle different problems. For instance, in the following scenario, I am naively assuming that the p(p) would also be equal to 0.1  given that the number of occurrences of p and q are equal, but I'm pretty sure there is more to it. Can someone please explain in very simple terms, how such a problem would be tackled, I've tried re-reading the chapter multiple times, and I feel I'm still clueless.

Consider the sample space: Ω={ p, q, r, s, t, u }
Consider the set of events: F ={ ∅, { p }, { q, r, s, t, u }, { q }, { p, r, s, t, u }, { p, q }, { r, s, t, u }, Ω}

The following probabilities are known:
P(q) = 0.1
P({ r, s, t, u }) = 0.3

Find P(p)

Comment: not suitable for SO. try https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

That set of events, **F**, says nothing about the probabilities of the outcomes; if the number of events which include `p` is equal to the number of events which include `q`, that tells you nothing about the probabilities of `p` and `q`, it's just an arbitrary decision about which of the 64 possible events to pay attention to.

The probabilities of all of the outcomes in the sample space must add up to 1, and the probability of an event is the sum of the probabilities of the outcomes that comprise it. So

```
1 = P({ p, q, r, s, t, u })
  = P(p) + P(q) + P({ r, s, t, u })

P(p) = 1 - P(q) - P({ r, s, t, u })
     = 1 - 0.1 - 0.3
     = 0.6
```